# Cannot get API to display data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to jQuery and not the best at programming but i cannot figure out how to fix this, I am using "TheList" API, and attempting to return JSON using jQuery but cannot get it to work. (https://api.list.co.uk/documentation)

The script always goes to failure no matter what, which baffles me since I got this working in regular JavaScript. The jQuery script is as follows below, I'm attempting to get the results of the JSON to be displayed in an html division called searchresults.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#searchForm").on("submit", function () {
        var data = $(this).serialize(); // this refers to submitted form, serizlize well see later in console:
        console.log(data);

        var display = $("#searchresults");
        display.text('CALCULATING');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/~lebreuillyj/project/webservice/search.php?" + data,
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(result)
            {
                var output = "";

                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) 
                {
                    output+= result[i].event["name"] + "<br />";
                }

                display.html(output);

                $("#searchresults").append(output);
            },
            error: function(xmlHttpRequest, statusMessage, httpCode) 
            { 
                alert("HTTP code=" + httpCode + " statusMessage=" + statusMessage + " full response text" + xmlHttpRequest.responseText); 
                alert("/~lebreuillyj/project/webservice/search.php?" + data);
            }
        });

    }); 
});
```

The Search script is also as follows:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

$apiKey = ;
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer {$apiKey}\r\n"
    )
);

$name = $_GET["name"]; 

if($name == "") 
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST");
}

elseif(isset($_GET["name"]))
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $data = file_get_contents('https://api.list.co.uk/v1/search?query=' .$name , false, $context);

    echo $data;
}

?>
```

The search script DOES work in my regular javascript file, but I wish to learn jQuery, so i can't imagine I have to change the search script at all, thanks for your time. (search script based on https://api.list.co.uk/getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my working copy.  I was able to get the code to work. I setup a local test. The key is the e.preventDefault(), which prevents the form from actually submitting, which caused problems. Also, you may want to remove your API key from your question. Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>
<script
              src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
              integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="searchForm" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="searchresults"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#searchForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize(); // this refers to submitted form, serizlize well see later in console:
        console.log(data);

        var display = $("#searchresults");
        display.text('CALCULATING');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/~lebreuillyj/project/webservice/search.php?" + data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result)
            {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                var output = "";
                for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++)
                {
                    output+= result[i]['name'] + "<br />";
                }
                display.append(output);

                $("#searchresults").append(output);
            },
            error: function(xmlHttpRequest, statusMessage, httpCode)
            {
                console.log("HTTP code=" + httpCode + " statusMessage=" + statusMessage + " full response text" + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                alert("/~lebreuillyj/project/webservice/search.php?" + data);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help, sorry for the late reply!